# NoMethodError in Demographics#demo_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Can someone help me with this error?
I have a collection_select which onchange triggers my javascript to ajax back to a Controller (Demographics) action (demo_set).  That is what I'm trying  to accomplish.
Lets walk through it:

View code:

```
<%= collection_select( :demographic, :demographic_id, Demographic.all, :id, :fullName,{}, {:onChange => "selectDemo(4);"}) %>
```

Javascript:

```
function selectDemo(id) {
//alert(id);
$.ajax({
  url: "/demographics/" + id + "/demo_set",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
}
```

As you can see, this AJAX is calling

```
 http://localhost:3000/demographics/4/demo_set
```

Going to this link produces the "NoMethodError in Demographics#demo_set" error

routes.rb:

```
get "/demographics/:id/demo_set" => "demographics#demo_set"
```

demographics_controller:

```
def demo_set
        render "activities/index"
end
```

activities_controller:

```
def index
    @activities = Activity.all
end
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show activities_controller?

Comment: Also, is that the actual and entire error message?  If not, please provide it.  Thx.

Comment: I'm still new to rails.

Comment: I added the index section of the activities_controller.  I'm still new to rails I didn't think the problem could be the activities controller.  I've been thinking that it is an ajax prob.  However, the error message states 'undefined method 'each' for NilClass'.  Additionally, there is a snippet of code <% @activities.each do |activity| %>

Comment: The error message indicates that you are calling method 'each' on a nil variable which is '@activities', if that message references that line. Your index action appears correct, as does your view snippet, as far as I can see from what you provided.  I expect one of two cases.  Either, the Activity.all reference is empty.  Or, there is some side effect that occurs between the action and the view that is clearing '@activities'.  If you can set breakpoints such as through pry, you could determine which.  I am using, and really love, RubyMine as an aside. The more you show me the more I can help.

Comment: Actually, you can try this.  Go to the project directory then enter rails console using "rails c".  Try the '@activities = Activity.all' assignment.  Rails should dump '@activities' as the return.  Is it nil or does it have at least one incidence of Activity?

Comment: Yes it returns one record.

Comment: Please post the activities index view. Can you verify the module and line that took the error?